# create an arrow using css

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is there any way to create an arrow like that in the following button, using CSS?

[image: arrow button]

I know how to create triangle-like arrows like this

```
#triangle_arrow {
        top: 3pt;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0.5em;
        height: 0.5em;
        border-right: 0.1em solid black;
        border-top: 0.1em solid black;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
```

but that line towards the arrow's corner is confusing me!

Comment: Why don't you simply use an image/icon?

Comment: Just use one of the many, many, [Unicode arrow symbols available](http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/)

Comment: **→** is &rarr; &rightarrow; &RightArrow; &srarr; &ShortRightArrow; See https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Check http://htmlarrows.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already there is way through which you could achieve this i.e. suggested by James, but you could even do this using `pseudo selectors` or using pre-defined icons using `font awesome` to get an arrow icon next to some tag, as below.

**Solution 1:**

```css
#box{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
}    
#box:before{
        top: 20px;
        right:10px;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0.5em;
        height: 0.5em;
        border-right: 0.1em solid white;
        border-top: 0.1em solid white;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        position:absolute;
}
#box > p:after{
  content:'';
  width:20px;
  height:1px;
  background:white;
  right:10px;
  top:24px;
  position:absolute;
}
#box > p{
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<p>Next</p>
</div>
```

**Solution 2 :**

```css
#box{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
}    
#box > p{
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#box > p > .fa{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="box">
<p>Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: one more quick question. Is there any way to change the font color in case of mouse hover? I tried both #box:hover and #box p:hover selectors but the arrow refuses to change its color :-(

Comment: @georgia font-color for what, can you add your jsfiddle.

Comment: @georgia check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1uby18rw/1/, hope solve your issue.

Comment: thank you so much once again @frnt. I'm sorry I didn't see your message in time to send you my fiddle. The problem was that I used border-color for both before and after pseudoelements. Sorry for bothering for that silly mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately for you, the → [HTML entity](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) exists, meaning you don't need to faff around with CSS triangles and instead can simply use `content` within a pseudo-element:

```css
button {
  background: #0898b8;
  border: 1px solid #0898b8;
  color: white;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

span::after {
  content: '→';
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>Next</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I think that if he wants to look exactly like in his design this won't help.

Comment: @Ionut that'd involve a simple case of finding a font which looks similar enough and applying it specifically to that pseudo-element.

Comment: Agreed, or using the image from his design would be a much simpler approach.

Comment: yeah as @lonut said, I was thinking about a way to make it look exactly like that, in both size and style. I guess I will use the image or change font style. Thank you for the answers anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Resizeable CSS-only arrow.
https://codepen.io/ArtZ91/pen/jjbOvG

```html
<div class="css-arrow top" style="width: 15px; height: 30px; zoom: 2;"></div>
```

```css
.css-arrow {
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  &:before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      top: 1px;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 1px;
      background: #000;
      zoom: 2;
  }
  &:after {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 57%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 57%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    border-radius: 0;
    zoom: 2;
  }
  &.right {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  &.bottom {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  &.left {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}
```